# GitHub Actions:secret env is empty

Tags: github-actions, secret-key

I encountered issue that env defined by secret env is empty. I want to use secret env in run syntax. I defined env of secret env like here.

```
     - name: Deploy
        env:
          GCP_PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}
        run: |
          date_time=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`
          IMAGE=gcr.io/$GCP_PROJECT_ID/web-api-server:$date_time
```

but `$GCP_PROJECT_ID` is empty.

```
invalid argument "gcr.io//web-api-server:20200718163842" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format
See 'docker build --help'
```

of course. I confirmed that `$GCP_PROJECT_ID` is defined at a secret.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is here.

> Organization secrets can only be used by public repositories on your plan.
> If you would like to use organization secrets in a private repository, you will need to upgrade your plan.

Answer (score 0):

**GitHub Organization-level secrets become accessible starting from the Team Plan on. (according to GH Support)**

*I encountered a similar issue, but in my case I just had a typo in the variable name.*

There is a page in the [GitHub wiki](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions#using-secrets-in-a-workflow) that explains how to use secrets.

**For powershell:**

```
steps:
  - shell: pwsh
    env:
      SUPER_SECRET: ${{ secrets.SuperSecret }}
    run: |
      example-command "$env:SUPER_SECRET"
```